# Problems in finding outliers and leverage points in non-linear regression

Tags: outliers, residuals, nonlinear-regression, diagnostic, nls

I'm implementing diagnostic of non-linear regression model $(y=ax^b)$. I'm trying to find out where outliers and leverage points in my model `(Regr.nls <- nls(NV ~ a*PIR^k, data = Regr, start = list (k = 0.5, a=0.5), trace = T)`

To find outliers I use the following code:

```
library(plyr)
library(ggvis)
Regr %>%
    mutate(rstud = ifelse(abs(rstudent(Regr.nls)) > 3, 'Больше 3', 'Не больше 3'),
         label = row.names(Regr),
         label = ifelse(rstud == 'Больше 3', label, '')) %>% 
  ggvis(~NV, ~ PIR,  fill = ~rstud) %>%
  layer_points() %>%
  add_axis("x", title = "Километров на литр") %>%
  add_axis("y", title = "Лошадиных сил") %>%
  add_legend("fill", title = "Стьюд.остатки") %>%
  layer_model_predictions(stroke := "red", model = 'lm') %>%
  layer_text(text := ~label, dy := -5, dx := 5)
```

However, there is an error:

```
Error in UseMethod("rstudent") : 
  no applicable method for 'rstudent' applied to an object of class "nls"
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Although this is a question about `R` code, it appears that a good answer would involve an explanation of what studentized residuals are and why computing them would require special code for nonlinear models.  These issues are of statistical interest.